# Is it possible to detect which key is clicked for JAVA key listener events? (key pressed, typed, or released)

Tags: java, netbeans, key, jtextfield, key-events

Is it possible to know which key is pressed in JAVA NetBeans in a jTextField? 
Also, when the enter key or esc key is pressed, to stop detecting it.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What is it you are hoping to achieve? An ActionListener should be use to monitor the field for presses of the "action" key, which is typically the enter key. You can use a DocumentListener to monitor changes to the contents of the textfield, which takes into consideration the user typing and pasting text, but also when setText is called

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's possible. Try something like this:

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();

                System.out.println("Code: "+keyCode+" , "+"Char: "+keyChar);

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    System.out.println("Enter pressed");
                    //do whatever you want here

                }else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                    System.out.println("Esc pressed");
                    //do whatever you want here
                }
            }
        };

this.textField.addKeyListener(keyListener);
```